# Azure count all VM's in VMSS using Azure Resource Graph

Tags: azure, kql

I am trying to count and get details about the **VM's** inside a scale set
but can't find a way to reach it.

I've tried the following query but it's just a start, and i can't complete it

```
where type == "microsoft.compute/virtualmachinescalesets" |
project properties.virtualMachine
```

Comment: The `details` you mean the osProfile,storageProfile,networkProfile, etc?

Comment: No i mean like the ```size``` of the inside VM, or ```private ip``` and so on information specific to the VM inside a scale set.

Answer (score 0):

This should give you the number of VMs in each set and some information on the scale set.

`az graph query -q "where type=~ 'microsoft.compute/virtualmachinescalesets'
| project subscriptionId, name, location, resourceGroup, Capacity = toint(sku.capacity), Tier = sku.name
| order by Capacity desc"`

Slighty butchered from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/governance/resource-graph/samples/advanced#vmss-capacity

Comment: and if i'd like to count only running VM's? or get the detailed information about the VM's, do you know any option?

Comment: Looking at the way the API works, it returns an object for each scale set when we use the above graph query. However, the required API endpoint we want for actual virtual machine details is `/subscriptions/xxxxxx/resourceGroups/my-rg/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachineScaleSets/MYSCALESET/virtualMachines`. I'm not sure how we can hit that endpoint using graph. I'll take a look and see if I can find a way.

Comment: I don't think there is a way to do this using graph queries. Could you use az cli or powershell instead?